# Inserting channel in category using await(discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Need help with putting new channel under a category. `.setParent(categoryID)` works but only for existing channels, so when I try to run my code it doesn't put it under the corresponding category.

Here's my code:

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
    if (message.content == "server") {
        try {
            await message.guild.setIcon('./icon.png');
            await message.guild.setName("MyServer");
            await message.guild.channels.create("new-channel", { type: 'text' }).setParent(categoryID);
            message.channel.send("Successfully edited server.");
        } catch {
            message.channel.send("Unknown error occurred while editing server.");
        }
    }
});
```

Please help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `categoryID` is defined, one solution is to wrap the channel creation inside of parentheses.

```js
(await message.guild.channels.create("new-channel", { type: 'text' })).setParent(categoryID);
```

Or you could use the `parent` property of [`GuildChannelManager.create()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create)'s options instead.

```js
await message.guild.channels.create("new-channel", { type: 'text', parent: categoryID });
```